# providing PayPal payments functionality to SaaS customers

Tags: paypal

I am developing a system that provides event signup/registration services. Event hosts should be able to offer online payment options to their customers via this system.

I need a scenario when event owner (assuming he/she already has proper PayPal Business account) configures the minimal amount of information in the system (like merchant ID) and then he's able to receive online payments without having to dive into technical details of the integration.

I have started with JavaScript button solution, but it turns out that it's not very customizable (for example I cannot change button title from 'Buy now' to 'Pay now').

Then I have spent some time researching Button Manager API, but it seems to be over-complicated to accomplish the task of just changing the button title.

Could somebody point me in a right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily change a standard button's image, it is simply an image URL in the client-facing code. If the javascript wrapper doesn't let you specify an image URL for some reason, don't use javascript buttons.  Create your own based on an unhosted button generated at paypal.com by unchecking the step 2 option to save the button at PayPal as well as the You are viewing your button page's option to remove code protection.  The "business" variable would then become your host's PayPal email or PayerID.

None of the above is the recommended route, which is to use the Express Checkout API and pass the parameter SUBJECT=hostspaypalemailaddress@domain.com (or PayerID) in your initial SetExpressCheckout call.   You probably also want SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole if this is your only payment option.

For onboarding new hosts you can use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/).